# Export Java as Jar application

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

i have a java project where i am accepting input from user and displaying output in console. I want to create a jar file so that other users can also run and use it. Can someone help me out with the steps. I am exporting jar file and running it but getting error " Could not find or load main class" while running.

Comment: add the manifest file in that having the name of the main class

Comment: or run java jar fullyqualified main class

Comment: @CoderNeji : I have added manifest.mf file with Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Enterprise

Comment: See this link http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing it through eclipse?

If yes, then follow below.

> 1. Make sure while exporting a jar to select an option under java as **Runnable Jar file**. Press next
> 2. Make sure you select Launch configuration, the one by which you run the project contains main method.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Netbean, it can build the jar file for you automatically. Just set your main class then click on clean and build.